# Apache2 on Ubuntu: I don't have installed apachectl

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I'm using Ubuntu Server 9.04 and I've installed Apache2 on it.

I want to restart my Apache gracefully but I only can restarting it using this command:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And if I'm not wrong it doesn't have graceful option parameter.

I don't have this command installed:

```
apachectl
```

thanks

**Update**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 graceful
 * Usage: /etc/init.d/apache2 {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|start-htcacheclean|stop-htcacheclean|status}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu apachectl is `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl`

Comment: @lain Ok thanks. Is it normal that I don't get any feedback message after the command ? For example, when I use "apache2 restart" I can see 2 lines "Apache restarting..." but apache2ctl just doesn't provide any additional info. Maybe just because everything went well ?

Comment: If there were any errors apache2ctl would report them.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/init.d/apache2` accepts `graceful` parameter. `reload` parameter does the same. You can use either:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

to pass `graceful` parameter to `apache2ctl`

**Edit:**

It exists.  look at source of `/etc/init.d/apache2`:

```
graceful | reload | force-reload)
    if ! $APACHE2CTL configtest > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                $APACHE2CTL configtest || true
                log_end_msg 1
                exit 1
            fi
            log_daemon_msg "Reloading web server config" "apache2"
    if pidof_apache > /dev/null ; then
                if $APACHE2CTL graceful $2 ; then
                    log_end_msg 0
                else
                    log_end_msg 1
                fi
            fi
;;
```

Comment: uhm.. not really apache2 graceful doesn't exist.. see my updated question.

Comment: About apache2 reload: is it exactly like graceful ?

Comment: Yes it does. See my edit.

Comment: ok. Maybe your version does not have it. I am working now on 10.04. But `reload` should do the same as `graceful` if in doubt look at source of `/etc/init.d/apache2` it should call at some point `$APACHE2CTL graceful`.